# Create Archimedean spiral with geographic coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, geolocation

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but here it his.

I want to create an Archimedean spiral based in some location. Lets say I have this set of geographic coordinates (`48.860770, 2.337655`). This will be the initial point of the spiral and I want to create `10` new locations.

I have this formula for calculating in `x, y coordinate`:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    angle = 0.1 * i;
    x = centerx + (a + b * angle) * Math.cos(angle);
    y = centery + (a + b * angle) * Math.sin(angle);
}
```

How can I change this to convert to geographic coordinates?

In my example, `centerx` would be `48.860770` and `centery` would be `2.337655`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a mathematician so may be my idea is flawed? There are more  clever people haunting this forum than I. A possible way of doing this is set your *centerx* and *centery* to zero and compute the range of values then add those to your real world XY position. An example of this is shown in the screen shot below.

So `i` is your count (I did 1 to 100), `angle` is your i * 0.1, `x` and `y` are the results of your equation where `centerx` and `centery` are always zero and `pX` and `pY` are your real world X and Y (48.860770, 2.337655) simply added to x and y. I've assumed `a` and `b` are 1.

[image: Creating the spiral in Minitab]

Comment: The main issue is spherical/spheroidal distance conversion; assuming the position is in degrees and the distance units are meters, then the spiral would be significantly smaller (and shaped slightly differently).

Comment: Many thanks. I'm now having trouble defining the angle but I will get there with trial and error. I'm using a=0.000001 and b=0.0001